# Visual C# 2013 StreamWriter acting erratically

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have been working on a small project in Visual Studio 2013 and I have run into the strangest problems with writing to a text file. Here's my code:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        File.Create(fileName).Close(); //Create/Overwrite file and close it.

        using (Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open)) { //Opens the file and creates a Stream, closes the file once finished.
            StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(stream);

            file.WriteLine("teststart");
            for (int i = 0; i < CHECK_BOX_COUNT; i++) {
                //file.WriteLine("test" + i);
                if (checkBoxes[i].Checked) 
                    file.WriteLine("t");
                else
                    file.WriteLine("f");
            }
            file.WriteLine("testend");
        }
    }
```

When I run the program with the preceding code, the text file is absolutely empty, yet it should write. But, interestingly enough, if I remove the // from before file.WriteLine("test" + i), then it writes to the file without issue.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can use the answer by @crumblyrock or use `file.Flush()` after the last `WriteLine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why it wasn't working - hopefully somebody else has some insight to that. My hunch is that is has to do with the way you are opening/closing the file, then creating a new stream, followed by a StreamWriter based on that stream.

One potential issue is that you aren't disposing of your StreamWriter object, just the underlying stream. StreamWriter should be disposed of too.

Here is a modified version that I just tested and it worked for me:

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fileName, false))
        { //Opens the file and creates a Stream, closes the file once finished.

            file.WriteLine("teststart");
            for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.Count; i++)
            {
                //file.WriteLine("test" + i);
                if (checkBoxes[i].Checked)
                    file.WriteLine("t");
                else
                    file.WriteLine("f");
            }
            file.WriteLine("testend");
        }
```

EDIT: I just re-tested your original code and confirmed my suspicion. if you dispose of your StreamWriter before disposing of the stream that it is based on (just stick it in a using statement), everything runs correctly.

Comment: Your fix worked perfectly. I guess that there's no need for having a Stream anyway. Thanks!